# Regex for a string with alpha numeric containing a '.' character

Tags: regex

I have not been able to find a proper regex to match any string not starting and ending with some condition.

This matches

```
AS.E
23.5
3.45
```

This doesn't match

```
.263
321.
.ASD
```

The regex can be alpha-numeric character with optional '.' character and it has to be with in range of 2-4(minimum 2 chars & maximum 4 chars).

I was able to create one ->

```
^[^\.][A-Z|0-9|\.]{2,4}$
```

but with this I couldn't achieve mask '.' character at the end of regex.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need pipes (`|`) inside brackets (`[]`). You should use a tool to help you build your regex, like https://regex101.com

Comment: Try [`^(?=.{2,4}$)[A-Z0-9]+\.[A-Z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NLSVCf/1)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew. Your regex helped me.

Comment: Shouldn't just this suffice `^[A-Z0-9]{1,2}\.[A-Z0-9]{1,2}`? I don't get why you need lookahead?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So it's 4 with dot, got it :) Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be [`^(?=.{2,4}$)[A-Z0-9]+\.?[A-Z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/NLSVCf/2). Sam, is that so?

Comment: Agree @zipa regex looks best for this task. [Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/fusi16/1). However question is not clear about the allowed amount of alphanumeric characters left and right of dot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most optimized but a working one. Created step by step:

1. The first character should be alphanumeric

   `^[a-zA-Z0-9]`
2. 0, 1 or 2 character alphanumeric or `.` but not matching end of string

   `[a-zA-Z0-9\.]{0,2}`
3. an alphanumeric character matching end of string

   `[a-zA-Z0-9]$`
4. Concatenate all of this to obtain your regex

   `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.]{0,2}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

***Edit:*** This regex allows multiple dots (up to 2)

Comment: I think OP only allows 1 dot per string. See *with optional '.' character*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well seen ! It complicates things... I'll try to edit to complete this

Comment: The solution is [here](https://regex101.com/r/NLSVCf/2). Else, you need to spell out all alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed correctly, you want to match all words that are

- Between 2 and 4 characters long ...
- ... and start and end with a character from `[A-Z0-9]`  ...
- ... and have characters from `[A-Z0-9.]` in the middle ...
- ... and are *not* preceded or followed by a `.`.

Try this regex to match all these substrings in a text:

```
(?<=^|[^.])[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.]{0,2}[A-Z0-9](?=$|[^.])
```

However, note that this will match the `AA` in `.AAAA.`. If you don't want this match, then please give more details on your requirements.

When you are only interested in the number of matches, but not the matched strings, then you could use

```
(^|[^.])[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.]{0,2}[A-Z0-9]($|[^.])
```

If you have one string, and want to know whether that string completely matches or not, then use

```
^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.]{0,2}[A-Z0-9]$
```

If there may be at most one `.` inside the match, replace the part `[A-Z0-9.]{0,2}` with `([A-Z0-9]?[A-Z0-9.]?|[A-Z0-9.]?[A-Z0-9]?)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to match what you say,

```
^[^\.][a-zA-Z0-9\.]{2,4}[^\.]$
```

Check the result here.. 
https://regex101.com/r/8BNdDg/3